# Make a tag with button class to disabled

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, tags

I have an a tag like below

```
<a class="button button-3d button-rounded btn-success" asp-page-handler="Download">
   <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
</a>
```

With a handler:

```
public async Task<FileResult> OnGetDownloadAsync()
{
    return File(await export.ExportAsync(), MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName + ".xlsx");
}
```

The export.ExportAsync call sometimes can be long. So I want to disable the button while the system is working. How can I achieve this? Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<a>` cannot obtain the status of the data transfer. Although it is disabled after clicking, the status of the label cannot be modified after the data request is completed. I suggest you use ajax because it can track the status of the request.

```
<button onclick="tap()" id="mybtn" class="btn-primary ">click</button>
@section Scripts{ 
<script>
function tap() {
    $('#mybtn').attr("class", "disabled");

    var url = '/?handler=Download';
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = "blob"; //  return type:blob
    xhr.onload = function (data, textStatus, request) {// finish request
        if (this.status === 200) {
            $('#mybtn').attr("class", "btn-primary");

            var blob = this.response;// get the return value
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            var fileName = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition').split(";")[1].split("=")[1];
            a.download = fileName

            a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            a.click();
        }
    };

    // send request
     xhr.send();
}

</script>
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Karney. It was a big help for me. 

Can you help me in one more thing? 

The file which I download the name it isn't same fileName + ".xlsx". It just a GUID. I don't know why.

Comment: Ok, you're welcome.Add `xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition')` to get the filename, I have added the method,  you can refer to it.